# Fade an image according to a condition and arrange them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In [this website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/), when you scroll down to the badge section,I have "locked and unlocked" badges.

Issues:

1. Can I make the locked badges faded. (as in hover effect we see a faded image)
2. Can we make the unlocked badges appear first and locked badges at the end.

css and js related to the locked and unlocked section:

```js
$.each($('.Portfolio-box'), function() {
  var count = $(this).children('.has-badge').attr('data-count');
  if (count > 0) {
    $(this).children('ul.locked').hide();
    $(this).children('ul.unlocked').show();
  } else {
    $(this).children('ul.locked').show();
    $(this).children('ul.unlocked').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.unlocked li:before {
  content: '\2713';
  display: inline-block;
  color: green;
  margin-left: -65px;
  padding: 0 9px 0 0;
}
.unlocked li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.locked li:before {
  content: '\274c';
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  margin-left: -65px;
  padding: 0 9px 0 0;
}
.locked li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Fiddle link of the entire site :https://jsfiddle.net/dkjz1z4k/1/

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Can I make the locked badges faded. (as in hover effect we see a faded image)

Best practice is to add current status class to the element's container. In your case it could be something like this:

```css
.locked-badge img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.locked-badge .badge-img {
  opacity: 0.7;    
}
```

```html
<div class="Portfolio-box locked-badge">
  <img src="#" class="badge-img"> 
</div>
```

It's always better to give classes to all elements witch designed in CSS. It will save you many time in the future and prevent some issues.

> 2.Can we make the unlocked badges appear first and locked badges at the end.

Please check this topic [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key). Another alternative is to use [lodash orderBy method](https://lodash.com/docs/#orderBy).

Comment: Thanks for trying.I cannot give a class and provide opacity to an image.The condition here is that ,when the count of a badge,which appears on the upper right side of a badge is '0' - the badge is locked and when greater than  '0' its unlocked.That will be changing constantly.So,when its locked with a point count of '0' the image of the badge needs to be faded.

Comment: The images are not static "locked or unlocked." They will basically be locked or unlocked according to the count value on the upper right of the badge.

Comment: I understand that this is dynamic class. After each change in count value you need to check in JavaScript if there are some milestone was achieved and change the locked/unlocked class in HTML accordingly.

Comment: The point is ,if its locked it should have a particular opacity(lets say 0.7 here),else remain as it is.If I change directly in the css with a class ,it wont serve the purpose.Thanks a lot.God bless

Comment: Please check created example to understand what do I mean: